# How do i make a slow transition for something that you cannot animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Video of the problem](https://streamable.com/kl6vr)

1. How to make a slow trasition of this (dim the images non hovered)?
2. How to make it not break and repeat when moving mouse really fast over all the images?

> ```
> $('.member>img').hover(function () {
>                             $('.member>img').css('filter', ' blur(2px) grayscale(50%) brightness(80%)')
>                             $(this).css('filter', ' blur(0px) grayscale(0%) brightness(100%)');
>                         }, function () {
>                             $('.member>img').css('filter', ' blur(0px) grayscale(0%) brightness(100%)');
>                         });
> ```

I tried this

```
$('.member>img').hover(function () {
                $('.member>img').one().css('filter', ' blur(2px) grayscale(50%) brightness(80%)')
                $(this).one().css('filter', ' blur(0px) grayscale(0%) brightness(100%)');
            }, function () {

                var grayscale = 50;
                var brightness = 80;
                var blur = 0; /*figure out blur later*/

                for (brightness = 80; brightness <= 100; brightness++) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.member>img').one().css('filter', ' blur(0px) grayscale(' + grayscale + '%) brightness(' + brightness + '%)');
                    }, 500);
                    grayscale -= 2.5;
                }
            });
```

But it just waits an interval before completing everything(not gradually)

Comment: first  i think you over complicate something with JS that can be easily done with CSS .. read about CSS transition and you will have what you want ... also you can animate filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :** I have removed the `opacity` property and used `::after` along with `background-color: rgba()` property instead. And the result is the closest I could get. See the edited code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/xyznavn/pen/PQNmyV).

Why are you trying to complicate something that can be achieved using plain css. I think *[this](https://codepen.io/xyznavn/pen/PQNmyV)* is pretty much what you were trying to do. I cannot provide you with exact working code based on the description but I hope you got the idea or the solution. And I think it is much more pretty and straight forward to use plain css solution.

Take a look at my code below.

HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="img"><img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1024x1024.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* setting background color to make it dark */
.holder {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 615px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* frame for the image making it responsive  I guess */
.img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
    transition: opacity .7s;

}
/* THE TRICK */
  /* dim the image container when hovered */
  .holder:hover .img  {
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: opacity 0.7s;
  }

  /* make the currently hovered image visible */
  .holder .img:hover  {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
/* END OF THE TRICK */

/* resize the image to fit the frame width maintaining the aspect ratio  */
.img img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why are you being downvoted, it works well and helps me progress.

Only thing is that i wanted to use dim, not opacity.

And I don't like dimming the whole container since i have gaps between images that i want to stay normal.

But thanks for the help!

Comment: I have a idea to dim the div i'll update it when I get free. If I helped you please consider accepting this answer. :)